# Slow internet speeds by comparison to Windows on the same machine

Tags: networking

UPDATE:  This seems to be an issue related to my ISP regardless of speeds being faster in Windows.  I'll close this out as resolved once I know more.

lspci output:  04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller (rev 04)

ethtool output:

Settings for enp4s0:

```
Supported ports: [ TP    MII ]
Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                        1000baseT/Full
                        2500baseT/Full
Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
Supported FEC modes: Not reported
Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                        1000baseT/Full
                        2500baseT/Full
Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
Link partner advertised link modes:  100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                     1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
                                     2500baseT/Full
Link partner advertised pause frame use: No
Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Link partner advertised FEC modes: Not reported
Speed: 2500Mb/s
Duplex: Full
Auto-negotiation: on
master-slave cfg: preferred slave
master-slave status: slave
Port: Twisted Pair
PHYAD: 0
Transceiver: external
MDI-X: Unknown
Supports Wake-on: pumbg
Wake-on: d
Link detected: yes
```

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release? How do you measure speed?

Comment: Ubuntu 22.10.  Noticed very slow SFTP uploads so I used speedtest-cli to check and it's absolute rubbish:


Download: 67.28 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed
Upload: 6.09 Mbit/s

Should be getting closer to 1400/40 (sad upload, but it's only hybrid fiber).